# GitHub ignorefiles

Tags: git, gitignore

I was using GitHub for more than a year, but right now I cannot handle ignoring
files.

I’m trying to ignore files that are generated by my IDE, and also ignore .pyc
files. But they keep appearing in my changes. I already tried to put:

```
experience/.idea
experience/.idea/*
```

Take a look at this screenshot:

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Be sure that you're using the right directory matching scheme, since you want to just block the directory.  For that, you want to change `experience/.idea/**` to just `experience/.idea/`.
2. Be sure that Git isn't tracking any of those files anymore by removing them from the stage via `git rm --cached <paths-to-ignore>`.

Answer (score 1):

If a file is already under version control, adding it to the `.gitignore` won't remove it from the index.

You need to remove it yourself using `git rm --cached <files>`